# How to avoid nested query in hibernate with views and filters

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, filter, view

I am using hibernate with views (annotation @Subselect and @Synchronize) and filters. The problem is hibernate encapsulate query (defined by 'value' property of @Subselect annotation)  and performances become very slow.

For example, if I write my own SQL query (which does not takes more than 100ms to execute) this is like that:

```
SELECT id,
       country_id,
       firstName,
       lastName
FROM client
WHERE client.country_id IN (2564,2558,1452,3652)
```

But if I using hibernate with filters, the generated query will be:

```
SELECT _this.id         AS id1_0_0,
       _this.country_id AS country_id2_0_0
       _this.firstName  AS firstName3_0_0,
       _this.lastName   AS lastName4_0_0
FROM (
   SELECT id,
          country_id,
          firstName,
          lastName
   FROM client
) _this
WHERE _this.country_id2_0_0 IN (2564,2558,1452,3652)
```

This means that the SQL generated by hibernate is slower than my sql query written by hand because all rows of the 'client' table (in nested query) are loaded, and filter operation is executed in parent query after having loaded all rows, this is stupid and provides very slow performances (1.7sec vs less than 100ms). So, does anyone known a method to avoid that ?

Comment: Could you post your `@Subselect` definition?

Comment: @Subselect is the annotation added on a class/field  (indeed, it is aptly named). But why filters do not applies to the nested query ?

Comment: Every decent optimizer should push the outer condition into the Derived Table, i.e. rewrite the 2nd query to the 1st. What's your DBMS?

Comment: maybe you could use criteria or hql for sub-selects, but why are you using @Subselect? I can see that you don't have nested queries in your own SQL query.

Comment: Sorry for my question, you are working with views, then can you put your code or part of it please?

Comment: How did you verify hibernate's generated query? The version of hibernate (used by our developers) appears to parameterize literals/scalars: Instead of "_this.country_id2_0_0 IN (2564,2558,1452,3652)", a trace on my RDBMS  reveals  "_this.country_id2_0_0 IN (@p0)" would be submitted. Perhaps parameterization is a hibernate configuration choice (not my area), but a use of parameters (as opposed to literals) can influence an RDBMS optimizer's chosen plan... And because each vendor's RDBMS optimizer is unique, we need to know the version and name of your RDBMS....

Answer (score 0):

I can see various problems and solutions here:

1. look if you can **avoid the @Subselect annotation** at all => if you can **create a view in the database** that returns the requested data, it will make the whole scenario and implications (hibernate mapping) much easier (why should Hibernate do or optimize something, that databases are really optimized and designed for)
2. **Hibernate does not generate code that is obviously optimized for your database (version)** => try to switch to a newer Hibernate version or influence it with db-specific hints/configuration (dialect, vendor etc.)
3. the **database does no good job at optimizing your query** (filter push down) and seems **very poor at such a common optimization strategy**
   => **try to switch to a newer db version or switch the DBMS** if possible (e.g. PostgreSQL, Oracle, ...) since more future problems are to be expected here

(for more specific details one really needs to have more background information on your tables, db version and annotated classes)